# Maths quiz for python - str object has no attribute

Tags: python, csv, math, store

I've been assigned a task to log student scores for a maths quiz

Below is my task:

The teacher wants to use the results from students taking these quizzes to log their performance. The system should store >the last three scores for each student.

every time I run my code I receive the error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

and when I convert into an int I get this error:
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

```
import csv
import os

name = input("enter your name: ")
classroom_num = input("enter your classroom number: ")
score = 5
print ("%s, you scored %d/10 questions correctly"%(name,score)) 
status = open ("state.txt","w") #Every time program is run +1 is added, so that column 1-3 are updated
with open ("state.txt","r") as f:
    state = f.read()
    if os.stat("state.txt").st_size == 0:
        status.write ("0")

state_ints = [ int(x) for x in state.split() ] #converts into int
addone = 1
if state_ints == 3: #If program is run more than 3 times the value in text file reset to 0
    state_ints = 0
    status.write (state_ints)
with open("Classroom {}.csv".format(classroom_num),"a+") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        if row in rows in row[0] != (name) in row: #Checks if name exists in file (if so name isn't appended to column)
            state_ints.append(addone) #Adds one everytime program is run so that score can be replaced for row 1-3
            status.write (state_ints)
            name_row = (row [0])
            name_row.append(name)
            score_row = (row (state_ints))
            score_row.append(score)
        else:
            state_ints.append(addone)
            status.write (state_ints)
            score_row = (row [state_ints])
            score_row.append(score)
status.close()
```

Also what other mistakes might I have made? What can I do to make this more efficient and complete this task?

Comment: `state_ints = state_ints.append(addone)` - I suggest you review your course materials about `append`.

Comment: I'm afraid "fix all the errors in my code" is not a specific enough question to be on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

A string is immutable. You can't change it. You need to make a new string or create a list and make a string of the list when you are done. Also `int` needs a string of a number to convert. A `None` type object is a variable with value `None`. `int` can't convert `None` to an integer so you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The line `for row in ("Classroom {}.csv".format(classroom_num)):` is iterating over a string, not a file. For each iteration, row is a single character string ('C' then 'l' etc).

`row[0]` is therefore the same as row and `name_row.append(...` is trying to call `append` on a string, hence the "'str' object has no attribute 'append'" error.

I can't see the `int()` call that's failing but the line `state_ints = state_ints.append(addone)` is setting `state_ints` to `None`. `append` modifies the list in place and returns `None`. You just want `state_ints.append(addone)`.

There are several other problems as well that suggest you might want to review a tutorial

- Putting a single item in brackets does nothing `(an_object)` is exactly the same as `an_object`.
- `row [state_ints]` is trying to use a list as an index (assuming you didn't mean to set it to `None`
  )
- `status.close` should be a method call
- `if state_ints == 3:` `state_ints` is a list at this point. It's never going to equal 3
- etc

Comment: I'm slightly confused, can you provide me with an example?

Comment: @MushtakNadim, An example of what?

Comment: So I have updated my code but when I run it no data is added to the csv file, also the "state" file remains at 0 so even if data is added, the last 3 scores won't be updated and will be appended to the row. Can you check if there is any problems causing this?

Answer (score 0):

See what's going on here?

```
>>> for row in ("Classroom {}.csv".format("2")):
...     print row
... 
C
l
a
s
s
r
o
o
m

2
.
c
s
v
>>>
```

You're not actually opening the file called "Classroom[number].csv" but, instead, you're iterating the characters in the file name. 
You can normally use `append` on the rows of a csv since they are typically transformed into lists (either manually via `split(",")` or via the `csv` module) but it fails here since your rows are, in fact, *not* rows/lists but characters/strings.

You can use `with open` and manually split by comma or use the `csv` module for parsing the file. The module approach:

```
>>> import csv
>>> 
>>> with open("Classroom {}.csv".format(classroom_num),"r") as f:
...     rows = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in rows:
...         print(row)
```

You keep re-using the file handle `f` when opening files. You also use both `with open()` and `f = open (...)`. This means that you might be trying to open the same file twice, read from a file you've opened in "append"-mode or other confusing/conflicting actions. Simply stick to `With open()` - that way, you won't have to manually close the files either.

Comment: @Holloway True: I'll add something about that `f = open (...)` line and re-defining file handles in the answer. `f` seems to be the only file handle/variable name used for files in the script.